# Get file size of multiple images using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, hash

I am using nested_form and am allowing users to upload multiple images. With each image though I want to validate the file size and then depending on that file size add a class in the view to, say, wrap the image in a red border so the user knows which image has failed.

The problem I am getting at the moment though is the first image in the hash is being evaluated and is then setting the value for all the other images after it in the hash.

```
 def max_file_size
  image = params[:animal][:animal_images_attributes]

   image.each do |k,v|
    img_cache = v["image_cache"]
    img = v["image"]

    tempfilepath = img.tempfile.path
    file_size = File.size(tempfilepath)
      if file_size > 1.megabytes
        @largeImage = true
      end
   end
 end
```

In my view then I have this

```
<!-- File Upload -->
<%= f.fields_for :animal_images do |build| %>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <% if build.object.image? %>
      <div class="<%= 'large_image' if @largeImage == true %>"> ***here***
       <%= image_tag build.object.image_url :small_animal_image %>
       <%= build.hidden_field :image_cache %>
       <%= build.label :image, 'Remove Image' %>
      <%= build.check_box :_destroy, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

So for each image I need the evaluation to take place and then assign the class if it is true.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
def max_file_size
 ...
  if file_size > 1.megabytes
    **@largeImage = true**
  end
 ...
end
```

Whatever class max_file_size is defined in is what is getting the largeImage flag set. I would seem that you want something more like:

```
img.largeImage = true
```

where you are setting the value on the individual image (may need to add this flag to your image object). Obviously, tough to debug without more code, but this jumps out at as me as your likely problem.